# adding text button to mainactivity java class

Tags: java, button, android-activity

What is the best way to add a **Text Button** when **clicked** to send to a new **Activity**?

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button imagebutton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    ImageButton I1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Intent intent;
    I1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.30F8.com/"));
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imagebutton;
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imagebutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


        imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.30F8.com/"));
                startActivity(i);;

            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v) {
              Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

add the button to your xml

### activity_main.xml

```
<Button
     android:id="button2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Your text goes here" />
```

Comment: I want to click the ImageButton and have it load a URL then below that have a separate Textbutton go to the next Activity

Comment: Let me give it a try here.